# Angular 2.0, Typescript and 'FORM_DIRECTIVES' module

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2.0 Alfa 35. When I am importing `FORM_DIRECTIVES` (which is a new name for `formDirectives` on Alfa 35) I am getting a Typescript error:

`error TS2305: Module '"angular2/angular2"' has no exported member 'FORM_DIRECTIVES'.`

Is it a bug in ts definitions? Can I fix/override it?

Comment: Could you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32150789/2435473

Comment: I did. This is the reason I knew to use `FORM_DIRECTIVES` instead of `formDirectives`...

Comment: @YanivEfraim can you set up a plnkr? I'm not able to reproduce it.

Comment: I will try to (not sure if I can get a plunker with ts compiler. The error is within the ts compiler). I will be able to add github repository that you can clone and install + serve.. 10X!

Comment: Did you upgrade recently? Try to delete node_modules and run npm install again

Answer (score 7):

As of today for Angular 2 Beta it should be:

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Angular >= RC.5**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup as we all know angular2 is in beta now so almost there is negligible chance of Breaking changes either it is the case of List of imports or any syntax, btw you can import necessary form imports from here...

```
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgIf  NgForm, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
```

for More list of all imports for angular2 beta you can refer here

- [List of all Imports updated to angular2 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34354666/5043867)

## update

as of updated angular2 RC there is change

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the previous answers given are no longer workable.  Angular2 now has an entirely different structure and package name in NPM.

For anything since Angular 2.0.0-rc.0 (from May 2, 2016), you have to use this for the old forms system:

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
```

**Update:** Or you can load it from here, if you are using the new Angular 2 forms system:

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';
```

You can read about it in the [Angular 2 ChangeLog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02).

Comment: How is input related to `FORM_DIRECTIVES`?

Comment: It's not, I pasted the wrong line of code in.  Fixed it.

Comment: I see. I haven't checked the `FORM_DIRECTIVES` export but the new forms stuff is in `@angular/forms` in RC.3

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Turns out you can import `FORM_DIRECTIVES` from `@angular/forms` as well.

Comment: If you use the old forms you have to import from `common` if you use the new forms then from `forms`. These two must not be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

`import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';`

worked for me with **angular2@2.0.0-alpha.35**

Answer (score -2):

As of today...

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/form';
```

Comment: "As of today" is quite useless description, version would be more useful to future readers.