# No angular.d.ts file with Tour of Heroes Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying the Tour of Heroes tutorial for Angular 2. The problem is after running 'npm install' with configuration as below there is no angular.d.ts file  Consequently I can't import. Am I using wrong versions of any dependencies?

```
import {bootstrap,  CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, OnInit} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "angular",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
        "systemjs": "0.19.6",
        "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
        "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
        "zone.js": "0.5.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
        "typescript": "^1.7.3"
    }
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: use 

    import {Component, View, Inject, Injectable, provide} from 'angular2/core';
    import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

Comment: because in angular2 beta imports has been changed as mentioned above in the comment.

Comment: CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES not available in angular2/core where do I import them from

Comment: import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgForm, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## List of all Imports updated to angular2 beta0.0

```
import {Component, View, Directive, Input, Output, Inject, Injectable, provide} from 'angular2/core'; 

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgIf  NgForm, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http'
```

if i add some more detail to this answer then **FORM_DIRECTIVES** includes following directives:

> `NgControlName`, `NgControlGroup`, `NgFormControl`, `NgModel`,
> `NgFormModel`, `NgForm`, `NgSelectOption`, `DefaultValueAccessor`,
> `CheckboxControlValueAccessor`, `SelectControlValueAccessor`,
> `NgRequiredValidator`

## Update 2

As of angular2 is in RC so there is breaking change in all imports here is the list if all updated imports -

```
angular2/core -> @angular/core
angular2/compiler -> @angular/compiler
angular2/common -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/common -> @angular/common
angular2/common_dom -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/browser -> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
angular2/platform/server -> @angular/platform-server
angular2/testing -> @angular/core/testing
angular2/upgrade -> @angular/upgrade
angular2/http -> @angular/http
angular2/router -> @angular/router
angular2/platform/testing/browser -> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing
```

Comment: yep, update the imports. now that its in beta, these are more stable. you can also find the latest ToH code in the angular.io repository, where i keep them updated.