# Angular2 not working giving error

Tags: node.js, angular

I am developing a angular2 app in typescript.

here is my component **login.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {FormBuilder,  FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'login',    
  injectables: [FormBuilder]
})
@View({
  template: '/scripts/src/components/login/login.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class login {

}
```

here is my **bootstrap.ts**

```
//import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {login} from './components/login/login';

bootstrap(login);
```

here is my **index.html** file

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/router.dev.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <login></login>
    </div>
    <script>
        System.import('scripts/src/bootstrap');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

but when i run my app it giving  me error

[image]

i'm unable to what wrong i have did, please help to run this app.

Comment: If you follow the example here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html It has you setup a config for systemjs that will probably fix your issue.

Comment: i have my all file in ts so do i change defaultExtension: 'js' to 'ts'

Comment: No. But make sure you're transpiling your code.

Comment: @jacques traceur might do that.

Comment: I don't know if it'll fix your issue but I can't see the angular2-polyfills.js file in all your script elements in your HTML page. Hope it helps you...

Comment: * compiler unable to find out the bootstrap file. * secondly use templateUrl instead of template. * make sure you project structure in the client folder and public folder is same. may be that's the reason behind no found of file bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading system.js from jspm.io, the default root path is on the jspm.io domain and your bootstrap is therefore not found.

Further, I do not believe there is such a thing as @View anymore. Put all the parameters in @Component.

You should really check out the latest code samples on http://angular.io. It has changed quite a bit lately. Getting the right libraries in the right order is essential.