# How to convert angularJS version 1.X controller into angular 2.X using EM6 ngupgrade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MessagesCtrl', function() {

$scope.self.list = [
{text: 'Hello, World!'},
{text: 'This is a message'},
{text: 'And this is another message'}
];

self.clear = function() {
$scope.self.list = [];
};
});
```

this is a controller written in angular. how can I convert this into angular 2 using EM6.

Comment: can any one share  tutorial for Upgrade angular 1.x into angular 2.x using EM6 or EM5

Comment: there is no "controller" in Angular 2. You either upgrade your directive or component via ngUpgrade or rewrite them in Angular 2. Let me know what you are looking for, I should be able to give you some examples.

Comment: In typescript "import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';" used for import UpgradeAdapter.I want to kow how this done using EM6 or EM 5

Comment: like this: - var adapter = new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter(); and then adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['yourApp']);

Comment: can u share some examples? thank you :)

Comment: I certainly can. But you need to elaborate your question a little bit, for example, the code of you current ng1.x directive that you want to upgrade and how you would like to use it in angular 2.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ATRu9J3g2G2BCPjSJYD1?p=info can u help me to upgrade this code

Comment: has networking issue at the moment, will try to work on the plunker later. as I said, you can't upgrade controller alone as there is no such thing in Angular 2. you need to create a directive that uses the controller and then upgrade that directive.

Comment: see https://plnkr.co/edit/03ljJfPvw3ESuL9QCQYH?p=preview, the fileReader is wrapped as a directive and used by a angular 2 component.

Comment: thank you!..but the variables are define as $scope.. is it OK..

Answer (score 1):

well upto my knowledge there are not alot of tutorials for the upgradation but yes thetre are few one.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html

well let me tell you about basic angular2 app.

in angular 1.x our main module is initilize  like this

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

but in the angular2 our main component started from the bootstraped file like this.

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from './app';

bootstrap(App,['here global level dependenices....']);
```

here app is our main component whihc is imported in this bootstrap file. so bootstraped is file our entry point of the app. and 
if we want to do some coding stuff like we work in the angular1.x controller here we do the same work in the class file (typescript class)
here i am posting one basic example like this.

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: "src/app.html",
    styleUrls: ['src/app.css'],
    directives: [ directives list here....],
})

export class App 
{ 
    // stuff you want to do here 
}
```

firstly we have to import angular2 bundles from the systemjs bundles like we imported Component and view in this example from the angular2/core.
there are alot of imports available for the angular2. you can [check out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34354666/5043867) and [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html)

Comment: in here upgrade done using type script. is there any tutorials in EM6

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/ check out here... dont know about es6 sorry.