# Ionic 2 import module errors

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to import the below listed modules, but i am getting an error for each of those modules with no exported members. I have manually checked the @angular/common folders and can't find these modules listed. Where can I get those?

```
 import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,  ControlGroup, Validators, AbstractControl} from '@angular/common';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form controls are available in `@angular/forms`.

```
import { FormBuilder,  FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
```

Check more [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

Comment: Thanks @suraj, I am not getting FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control Group, the rest are fine. any idea where do i get them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300549/angular-2-0-typescript-and-form-directives-module

Comment: And ControlGroup is now FormGroup https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup